# Disable filter pane (or at least ensure it's collapsed by default)

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I've successfully embedded a report but every time I navigate to another page in the report, I'm finding that the filter pane is visible and expanded by default.

I've tried setting ensuring the pane is collapsed in desktop, set the hid for viewers button on the panes in the reports.

What's most frustrating is there are no filters available!

This is my embed configuration:

```js
var embedConfiguration = {
                type: 'report'
                , id: data.reportId 
                , embedUrl: data.embedUrl
                , tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed
                , accessToken: data.accessToken
                , settings: {
                    layoutType: width >= 1312 ? models.LayoutType.Master : models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
                    , panes: {
                        filters: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        pageNavigation: {
                            visible: false
                        }
                    }    
                }
            };
```

I've also added the tag powerbi-settings-filter-pane-enabled="false" to the div(s) where reports will appear.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of the Power BI JavaScipt client? This syntax is pretty new (like since the last couple of weeks). Try to use the old one, when there are properties in `settings`, i.e. `settings: { filterPaneEnabled: false }`.

Comment: Hi. Will check. The navigation pane isn’t appearing so I’m happy that the version supports what I’m trying to do. 

I’ve tried the older approach too and the behaviour is the same, the filter pane is only absent on the landing page and appears when you click on links taking you to other pages in the report.

Comment: I am definitely using the latest version of the powerbi-client module (2.11).

Comment: And the latest beta 2.12.1 also exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks for taking the time to read this and respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked out that the Bookmark action was used to navigate between pages and changing this to Page Navigation didn't cause the filter pane to appear. That's only 1 week I'm not getting back!

Comment: I raised this with Microsoft and turns out it's a known issue and the fix should be out by the end of the month (probably sooner).